# HTTP Request's response shows error like 401"Unauthorized" for "HttpClient4" Implementation

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to Jmeter. I want load testing for my web url. Web application is on Intranet.In My Http Request, I send request for the URL Home Page with Implementation as "HttpClient4". Method is "GET". Then View Result Tree shows error like "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials" in the Response.

However, when I send same request with Implementation as "JAVA" then it works perfectly. I got correct response from the server without providing any credential details. I am using Jmeter version 3.2

Can anyone tell me how can I test same application with "HttpClient4" Implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

There were several [changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) improving/fixing HttpClient4

I encourage you to try the latest version, JMeter 5.0, to check if the issue reproduce, and if it's reproducible [open an issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=JMeter) to JMeter with more details

> Bug 62529 - Updated to httpclient-4.5.6
>
> Since JMeter 5.0, when using default HC4 Implementation, JMeter will reset HTTP state (SSL State + Connections) on each thread group iteration. If you don't want this behaviour, set httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=false
>
> Bug 58757 - HTTP Request : Updated deprecated methods of HttpComponents to last APIs of httpclient-4.5.X.
>
> Bug 60015 - Multipart/form-data works only for POST using HTTPClient4 while it should for PUT, DELETE, …

Comment: I tried after updating Jmeter 5. But still same issue.